# Solr atomic updates are generating new documents every time

Tags: solr

I am using latest solr (4.10.1) and want to perform a lot of atomic updates on very big documents (frequent ACL changes).

I've used Luke to look into the index after the updates and it seems that the **solr copies the whole document again** with new `_version_` field and my atomic field change.

What happens if the same document is updated 1 mio. times? Are there really 1 mio. copies of the same document?

I've looked into the solr source and there is no way to specify an own `_version_` value since it is **always** replaced with a new timestamp. Loading the old document for deletion of the old version is not an option because of performance.

So is there any other way to prevent solr from generating document copies again and again?

Comment: You mean in the index, after the first atomic update of a given document, you see twice the same document, the only differences being the version number and the field that you atomically changed?

Comment: exactly. each atomic update request creates a new copy of the updated document. The `docId` is also different of course.

Comment: Do you use a unique ID? Something like: <fieldType name="uuid" class="solr.UUIDField" indexed="true" /> and specify it in the update request?

Comment: of course. how else could i update a document? but my uid is of type string.

Comment: Just checking :) Not sure what's going on then, sorry...

Comment: did you commit after doing the atomic updates?

Comment: yes, soft and hard. I could not see the document in the index otherwise. I do open the index with Luke in read only mode, so the document would not be there if i did not commit it.

Answer (score 0):

For your original problem, you should try doing it the other way. Search for "Solr ACL" and you'll find a lot of discussions and some options. Including [ManifoldCF](http://manifoldcf.apache.org/en_US/index.html#What+Is+Apache+ManifoldCF%3F) as one option.